# operations on validated text fields in jsf

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm Using Primefaces 3.5. I have around 10 input text fields in my .xhtml page.Few text fields are made mandatory with attribute `required="true"`.

I have a search button that displays Data from Database in a Data Table.The functionality of my page is to insert the values into these fields by `on row select()` the data in the Data Table of Search Button.

The Problem here is the data is inserting into the Fields which are highlighted with the red border ie fields with validations applied.

Example:

[image]

Transport Field has no validation but it had value that has to be inserted. These type of things are happening to many of my Input Fields.
Please give me some suggestions.

.xhtml file is:

```
 <p:inputText id="email" value="#{addcust.c.email}" required="true"
  validatorMessage="Enter Valid Email">
          <f:validateRegex pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"/></p:inputText>
<h:outputLabel value="Transport"></h:outputLabel>
 <p:inputText value="#{addcust.c.transport}"  </p:inputText>

    <p:commandButton value="add" type="submit" update=":form,:msg"   actionListener="#{addcust.onAddSelect}"</p:commandButton>
<p:commandButton value="Search" type="submit"  onclick="ser.show() "></p:commandButton>
<p:dialog id="dialog11" header=" Search" widgetVar="ser" resizable="false" showEffect="fade"
                                  hideEffect="explode" >
                            <p:dataTable id="dt" var="sd" value="#{addcust.al}" selection="#{addcust.c}">
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":form" listener="#{addcust.onRowSelect}"
                                        oncomplete="ser.hide()"/>
 <p:column>
           <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Email"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{sd.email}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Transport"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{sd.transport}"/>
                                </p:column>
                            </p:dataTable>
```

customerbean.java

```
public class customerbean {
  private String email;
 private String transport;

    public String getTransport() {
        return transport;
    }

    public void setTransport(String transport) {
        this.transport = transport;
    }
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
```

addcust.java

```
    public customerbean c = new customerbean();
    public ArrayList<customerbean> al;
   public void onAddSelect(){
   // Inserted my values into customer table.
}

     public void onSearchSelect() {
        try {
            st = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from customer where cmpid=" + getCurrcompanyid() + "");
            al = new ArrayList<customerbean>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                customerbean s = new customerbean();
                s.setEmail(rs.getString(1));
                s.setTransport(rs.getString(2));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) throws SQLException {
        customerbean r = (customerbean)event.getObject();
       c = r;
}
```

If I'm not clear enough please leave me a comment .Thanks for Reading.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: You should put a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).